# Custom config file in the client using Linux

Tags: linux

I have an application that stores some information in a *.conf file, something like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
somevar = blablabla
othervar = blebleble
```

Is there a usual place on a linux system where I can put this file when it is being installed or should I put it on a place related to the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what your application is.

If it is the usual F/LOSS, then global config goes under `/etc/`, per-user goes under `$HOME/`. As per convention, config files under `$HOME` have the same name as under `/etc/` but start with `.` - that means they are *hidden* and do not show up (`ls`) unless you tell to specifically show them (`ls -a`, `ls -A`). If you have multiple configs, then use subdirectory under `/etc/` or `$HOME` (again with the `.`). Check for example what [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-config-files) says about that.

If this is some commercial application which is going to be installed manually/semi-automatically somewhere under `/opt/<progname>`, then put the configs (you would likely have only global ones) under `/opt/<progname>/etc`. General rule in the case is to mimic the usual *NIX hierarchy (except for `$HOME`), but rooted under your `/etc/<progname>` subdirectory.

Also note that Windows-style .ini files are not very well accepted on *NIX systems: it is hard to work with them from command line. If possible, use the [properties-style config file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties). E.g. the config you have quoted above would look like:

```
DEFAULT.somevar = blablabla
DEFAULT.othervar = blebleble
```

Answer (score 4):

System-wide configuration is stored under `/etc`. Per-user configuration is stored in a hidden file in the user's home directory.